# WCS band metadata description on mapserver 7,4.4 is not being outputed

Tags: mapserver, metadata, wcs

I am trying to set proper metadata on a mapserver 7.4.4 instance, based on this example:

https://mapserver.org/nl_NL/ogc/wcs_format.html#grib2-output-format

And WCS paramters like:

(wcs|ows)_band_interpretation
(wcs|ows)_band_uom

That are well  described on:

https://mapserver.org/ogc/wcs_server.html#new-band-related-metadata-entries

I have implemented something like this for testing:

```
LAYER
        NAME "MostProbable"
        PROJECTION
            'init=epsg:4326'
        END #PROJECTION
        EXTENT -180.0 -61.06747625006139 179.9999424001524 83.99916720600001
       METADATA
            'ows_title' 'WRB most probable class'
            'wcs_label' 'MostProbable'
            'wcs_rangeset_name' 'range1'
            'wcs_rangeset_label' 'label1'
            'ows_extent' '-180.0 -61.06747625006139 179.9999424001524 83.99916720600001'
            'ows_srs' 'EPSG:4326 EPSG:152160 EPSG:3857 EPSG:54009 EPSG:54012'
            'ows_abstract' ''
            'ows_keywordlist' ''
            'wcs_formats' 'GEOTIFF_BYTE'
            "wcs_bandcount" "1"
            "wcs_band_names" "band1"

            #default values
            "wcs_band_interpretation"   "Allo Allo this is nighthawk"
            "wcs_band_uom"              "class"
            "wcs_band_definition"       "test Definition"
            "wcs_band_description"      "Come in London"
            "wcs_interval"              "0 125"
            "wcs_significant_figures"   "3"

            #specific band values
            "band1_band_interpretation" "Listen very carefully, I shall say this only once"
            "band1_band_uom"            "class2"
            "band1_band_definition"     "SpecificDefinition"
            "band1_band_description"    "This is a specific description"
            "band1_interval"            "0 255"
        END
```

Doing a `DescribeCoverage`:

https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/wrb.map&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=DescribeCoverage&COVERAGEID=MostProbable

I dont see any changes on the response for example uom stays the default: `<swe:uom code="W.m-2.Sr-1"/>`

What could be the problem for the metadata not to be displaied on the DescribeCoverage response description, maybe I am missing something ???